# If submenu li has more than 5 li's create a new ul and place remaining list items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, html-lists

I am basically trying to check if my submenu has more than five list items, and if it does grab the remaining list item's and place them inside a new ul that is outside of the current parent ul using jquery. it gets complicated because of the structure of the list.

Here is the DOM structure:

```
<ul id="nav" class="se test">
<li id="menu1" class="page-1307 parent-menu parent">
    <div class="nav-inner">
        <a class="menulink" id="menuitem1" onclick="return false" href="#">test<span class="toggle"></span></a>
        <ul id="ie1" class="plain">
            <li class="parent-menu parent"><a href="test">test<span class="toggle"></span></a>
                <div class="submenu-wrapper">
                    <ul class="plain">
                        <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
           </li>
           <li class="parent-menu parent"><a href="test">test<span class="toggle"></span></a>
                <div class="submenu-wrapper">
                    <ul class="plain">
                        <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="menu2" class="menulink page-7">
    <div class="nav-inner">
        <a href="test">test</a>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Basically i need to grab those remaining list items and place them in a new li.parent-menu.parent that includes the children div.sub-menu-wrapper and the ul.plain. the actual remaining list items would go inside the ul.plain of the new li.parent-menu. i hope thi makes since. i have been stuck on this for a day or two and unble to figure it out. any help would be greatly apprecitated, thank you.

This is what i am striving for, keep in mind it is dynamic.[image]

Comment: Sure, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is there a purpose for a new parent ul in the DOM? You could potentially use an nth-child css solution if it is strictly for styling purposes.

Comment: I have tried iterating through each li with-in a submenu-wrapper and check to see if li.length is greater than five if it is then grab the remaining list items and push them to a new array. take the array and place inside a newly created li.parent-menu that is wrapped by .submenu-wrapper and ul.plain. I got frustrated and started from scratch, otherwise I would have posted my last attempt. I will post my new attempt in about ten minutes. hopefully i can figure it out.

Comment: The way it needs to be styled is why I need to create the new element if over five. the menu is created dynamically using php

Comment: I added a picture to show what the styling should look like

Comment: [Is this](http://jsfiddle.net/yhp1sfco/) what you want? Or at least does it get you on track?

Comment: It got me on track, thank you. I posted the final answer below. thank you everyone for your help. not sure why i got down votes, please explain.

Comment: @Musefan thank you for your help, your answer was actually the one I was looking for. if you post as an answer I will mark as the answer and upvote.

Answer (score 2):

you can:

1. Loop all ul in your document
2. foreach element count children
3. if found li number under an ul element is > 5
4. create a new list with the html of the required list

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.submenu-wrapper').each(function(){
        var count_li=0; 
        var i=1;
        $(this).children('ul').children('li').each(function(){
            count_li++;
            if(count_li>5 && i==1){
               $(document.body).append('<ul id="newlist"></ul>');
               $('#newlist').append($(this).nextUntil($(this).last()).andSelf());
               i++;
            }
         });
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav" class="se test">
<li id="menu1" class="page-1307 parent-menu parent">
    <div class="nav-inner">
        <a class="menulink" id="menuitem1" onclick="return false" href="#">test<span class="toggle"></span></a>
        <ul id="ie1" class="plain">
            <li class="parent-menu parent"><a href="test">test<span class="toggle"></span></a>
                <div class="submenu-wrapper">
                    <ul class="plain">
                        <li><a href="test">test11</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test12</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test13</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test14</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test15</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test16</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test17</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
           </li>
           <li class="parent-menu parent"><a href="test">test<span class="toggle"></span></a>
                <div class="submenu-wrapper">
                    <ul class="plain">
                        <li><a href="test">test21</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test22</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test23</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test">test24</a></li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="menu2" class="menulink page-7">
    <div class="nav-inner">
        <a href="test">test</a>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is really close to what i am trying to do except i need to remove the remaining list items after five and take those remaining list items and place in new ul. i will take what you have and try and mold it to what i need, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final answer I was looking for:

```
megaMenu: function(){
    function addNewList(current, newItems) {
        var newList = $('<li class="parent-menu parent newLi">');
        var div = $('<div class="submenu-wrapper">');
        newList.append(div);
        var ul = $('<ul class="plain">');
        div.append(ul);
        for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
            ul.append(newItems[i]);
        }
        current.after(newList);
        return newList;
    }
    function splitLists() {
        var allLists = $(".plain > li.parent-menu");
        for (var i = 0; i < allLists.length; i++) {
            var currentList = $(allLists[i]);
            var items = currentList.find("li");

            if (items.length > 5) {
                var temp = [];
                for (var j = 5; j < items.length; j++) {
                    temp.push($(items[j]));
                    if (temp.length == 5) {
                        currentList = addNewList(currentList, temp);
                        temp = [];
                    }
                }
                if (temp.length > 0) {
                    currentList = addNewList(currentList, temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    splitLists();
}
```

Comment: I apologize for the delay in answers i was in a team meeting. Again thank you for the help and direction.

Answer (score 0):

After some clarification via comments it seems you are looking for something like this. I have commented the code to explain the logic behind the process:

```
// function for adding a new LI item.
function addNewList(current, newItems) {
    // Create the new li node.
    var newList = $('<li class="parent-menu parent">');

    // Add the initial a link.
    newList.append('<a href="test">test<span class="toggle"></span></a>');

    // Create and append the submenu-wrapper div to our new list item.
    var div = $('<div class="submenu-wrapper">');
    newList.append(div);

    // Create and append the new ul node to our submenu-wrapper div.
    var ul = $('<ul class="plain">');
    div.append(ul);

    // Loop the 5 (or less) items that have been specified and add them to our new list.
    for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
        // Using append will move the elements that already exist in the original place.
        ul.append(newItems[i]);
    }

    // Add our new list item to the DOM.
    current.after(newList);

    return newList;
}

// Base function to split the lists as required.
function splitLists() {

    // Get all the lists that we want to process.
    var allLists = $(".plain > li.parent-menu");

    // Loop each list and process.
    for (var i = 0; i < allLists.length; i++) {
        var currentList = $(allLists[i]);

        // Get the sub-items that we need to split.
        var items = currentList.find("li");

        // We only care about lists that are more than 5 items.
        if (items.length > 5) {
            // Create array to store the items that we want to move (any after first 5)
            var temp = [];
            // Start at the 6th item an start moving them in blocks of 5.
            for (var j = 5; j < items.length; j++) {
                // Add the item to move to our temp array.
                temp.push($(items[j]));

                // If we have 5 in our temp array then move them to new list.
                if (temp.length == 5) {
                    // Move items with helper function.
                    currentList = addNewList(currentList, temp);
                    // Clear the temp array ready for the next set of items.
                    temp = [];
                }
            }
            // If we have any spare ones that didn't get handle in the length == 5 check, then process them now.
            if (temp.length > 0) {
                currentList = addNewList(currentList, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Run the process.
splitLists();
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4cmyf7ck/)